# Floating image despite using [h]

Tags: graphics, floats, diagrams

I'm struggling to get my picture to appear straight after the text. I have used the following code:

```
\begin{figure}[h]
  \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{"Interaction Plot - Data1".png}
  \caption{Interaction Plot for Data Set 1}
  \label{fig:Interaction Plot for Data Set 1}
\end{figure}
```

It currently appears several pages later after all sections.

Comment: Hi, welcome to the site. `h` has never meant "put the float right here, period". If you want to essentially disable the floating, add `\usepackage{float}`, and use `H` instead of `h`.

Comment: If you want more information about float placement in general, have a look at the five highest voted questions that are tagged with [tag:floats] and [tag:positioning]: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/floats+positioning?sort=votes&pageSize=5 (well, perhaps not the fourth one, but the rest)

Comment: And in general `H` is not advised. Use `[htbp]` instead, then you should appear as close to this point as possible.